# Find two % separated by max 150 characters using regex

Tags: regex

How do I find two % separated by **max** 150 characters using regex?

What is the regex expression for this?

**Edit**

Including newlines (on Windows \r\n).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one works:

```
%[^%]{0,150}%
```

It matches every two `%` (and everything in between except `%`) separated by maximum 150 characters.

EDIT: If you have trouble with matching line breaks, you might try `%(.|\r\n|\r|\n){0,150}%`

Comment: Sorry I forgot to say, I want newlines included in those 150 chars.

Comment: Well, it should include newlines. Which RegEx engine are you using?

Comment: I am using regex functionality in Total Commander -> Commands->Search ->Find text

Comment: `[^%]` means everything except `%`. So also newlines. Look at this: http://regexr.com/3gq65

Comment: You might try `%(.|\r\n|\r|\n){0,150}%`

Comment: How do I specify I want one semicolon in those 150 cahrs?

Comment: That's difficult. You could use `%(.|\r\n|\r|\n){0,150};(.|\r\n|\r|\n){0,150}%`, but this means there can be 150 chars before and after the semicolon. If you change the `150` to `75`, you get a maximum of 151 chars between the `%`s, but you won't match `% -> 20 chars -> semicolon -> 120 chars -> %` - you know what i mean? BTW if my answer solved your initial problem, i would be happy if you accepted it.